# Bluetooth cannot search detect any device

Tags: bluetooth

I have Loki installed updated up to today (7-Oct-2017). My bluetooth cannot search any device recently and keep turning. The wingpanel and system setting both can turn on and off bluetooth but can never search any device nearby. Here is the output as requested in other posts:

`root@irvin-ElementaryOS:/# lspci -nnk|grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2114]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8723ae, wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d3:3394 IMC Networks Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.147641] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.930979] usb 2-7: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[    5.145277] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    5.145314] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.145323] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.145327] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.145335] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.203372] rtl8723ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[    5.231144] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[    5.231151] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[    6.338715] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.338721] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.338728] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.650764] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.650776] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.650783] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
root@irvin-ElementaryOS:/#`

Elementary OS is getting great!! Please help to make it better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to resize my Bluetooth window (Device search) for it to show an actual list of devices it sees. Heres to hoping the answer is just that simple.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm just too stupid that I didn't try this... It's solved, I found the devices!

Comment: You would probably believe how long it took me to figure it out then lol, cheers!